# Xcode not displaying compile errors

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, compiler-errors, xcode8

I'm working in a specific Xcode project  and deliberatly making errors in my code (like using *undeclared* variables), but Xcode doesnt seem to show any compile errors in my code.

- It shows errors only when its build or clean.
- Tried clean and build, cleaning derived data and restarted both Xcode and system, none of it works.
- Using Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) and Swift 3

Comment: You mean that errors are not shown during editing? Is the "Show live issues" option set in the Xcode general preferences?

Comment: @MartinR - "show live isuues " is set . I have this issue only in one specific project.

Comment: Errors are not shown during editing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Besides the `DerivedData` folder, also try cleaning Xcode *caches* completely:

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/
```

I would recommend also killing the `SourceKit` process — always a source of issues these days! — but since you are already did a full reboot, so looks like you are good there.

If everything fails, you might consider upgrading to the latest Xcode, version 8.3. Just be aware that:

> Xcode 8.3 no longer supports Swift 2.3. Please migrate your projects containing Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3 syntax by opening the project and choosing Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax.

Comment: Cleaned the cache , issue still remains there. It's shown only in one project ,other projects works perfectly. So.. Do I need to upgrade to xcode 8.3?

Comment: @ajithKumark I would definitely upgrade when you get a break. That is, if you are using Swift 3, otherwise you might need to spare some time do it properly... see my updated answer for details.

Comment: @ajithKumark I might have just found the answer to your issue: To make it work, you have to check both the *show live issues* in Project setting as well as the one in Preference > General.

Comment: Its perfect... Checked "show live issues" in File -> workspace settings , now it works fine . Thanks Paulo..

Answer (score 21):

Disable `Show live issues` (in Xcode settings - general) solved for me on Xcode 14.2

Solution source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715103?answerId=749502022#749502022

Comment: God bless you, I spend almost half a year in Report Navigator to check errors, because of this issue until I found your answer.

Comment: You should at least mention where someone can find the "Show live issues" setting.

Comment: I spent almost 6 months . finally get it. Thanks

Comment: @sagarthecoder glad to hep you!

Answer (score 2):

Project Settings, "Show all issues" fixed it for me.

Comment: Interesting. Annoying it started to do it suddenly. I have AVR-C projects that use one mac target to run code sense and then external build systems for everything else. Stupidly enough is is not actually about the scheme, but the target. I did delete the mac scheme, but not the target. Still, I get many errors from the mac target, as there is AVR specific stuff that it does not recognise

Comment: it would be more clear to say where can we find "Project Settings".

Comment: There's no mention of where this setting can be found in Xcode and it doesn't say whether you should enable or disable the setting. This answer could be greatly improved by mentioning those two things.

Comment: The answer is not clear

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to first ensure all of my Xcode Targets had valid Signing & Capabilities like a development Team selected... then I was able to update all of my Targets to Swift 5 using the warning that was presented to me.  Immediately after all of the targets were all updated to Swift 5 and the Provisioning was fixed, the red errors were flagged again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Xcode 13.3 with Swift version 5.5

Upgrading to Xcode version 14.1 (14B47b) which also upgrades Swift tools to version 5.7.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that the target membership of the files is unchecked.

Right-click the file with the errors not showing, and click on `Show File Inspection`. Under `Target Membership`, check the box. Somehow all my files are unchecked, and the errors work just fine after checking all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Disable "show live issues" as mentioned above, attached is a screen shot [image]